# Keytool error while converting p12 to jks

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, jks, pkcs#12

I have a p12 certificate and I am trying to convert it into a jks keystore.The p12 certificate was created without a password. This is the command I'm using-

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore [Source.p12] -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcalias [Src alias] -destkeystore [destination.jks] -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass [Some pass] -destalias [Some alias]`

The configurable values are inside square brackets. When I execute this I am prompted for the source keystore password. Since Source doesn't have a password I just hit enter but then I am met with a keytool error stating "invalid null input".

```
Enter source keystore password:

*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in the srckeystore*
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide the srckeystore password.                *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

keytool error: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input
```

Surprisingly if I use the list command that is - `keytool -list -storetype PKCS12 -keystore elastic-certificates.p12 -v` , I am again prompted for a password but this time it works on hitting enter and i get the alias and other information.

Any leads on what may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the above command to have src password as blank string "" worked and it didn't prompt me again for a password. This is what worked-

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore [Source.p12] -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcalias [Src alias] -srcstorepass "" -destkeystore [destination.jks] -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass [Some pass] -destalias [Some alias]
```